# force use bootstrap datepicker and neglect jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the both bootstrap datepicker and jQuery ui in my application web but i want to applicate only the bootstrap datepicker on datepicker input and neglect jquery ui.

I'm using the noConflict method of bootstrap-datepicker but it didn't solve my problem.

how can I force use the bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: Any code sample?